# Caching the activity when switching between Activities with ActionBar list navigation

Tags: android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I'm using Spinner-based Action Bar (with ActionBarSherlock) navigation in my app, this sort of thing:

[image: This]

Switching between Activities is very slow. I have realised that on every switch, it is creating a new Activity, but the old Activities are kept in memory, and aren't recreated when pressing back.

I would like to be able to only recreate the Activity only when required, but otherwise to just use the Activity that has previously been created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add:
    android:launchMode="singleTask"

to your AndroidManifest

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for! It seems to speed up the transitions (after the first one) quite a lot :D